# How to get the cross contract matrix from two 2-dim tensors in tensorflow?

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, multidimensional-array, vectorization

```
import tensorflow as tf 
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.variable_scope('masssdsms'):
        a = tf.get_variable('a', [1000,24,128], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1) )
        b = tf.get_variable('b', [1000,15,128], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1) )
```

I want to get a new tensor named `c` from `a` and `b`.
1000 is the batch size, and `c`'s shape should be `(1000,20, 10, 1)`. For every instance from `a` and `b`: `ai` and `bi`, they are both two dimensional tensors. 
The new instance `ci` is the result of `ai` and `bi` and it has `20 * 10 = 200` elements, that every element is the dot product of ai and bi with 128 dimension respectively. So there are 200 dot products results in sum. The ci is more like a 2-D image.

[image]

How can I initialize this operation?

Modified:
When I take the codes in usage, the operation of **dot product** should be replaced with some other function like guassian distance, or cosine distance etc, which is contact notation in the graph. 
So I need to a common method to do this.

Here is what I design, but I am not sure whether it is a efficient way to do this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.variable_scope('masssdsms'):
        a = tf.get_variable('a', [1000,24,128], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1) )
        b = tf.get_variable('b', [1000,15,128], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1) )
        i = 999 # for i in range(1000):
        ai = tf.slice(a,[i,0,0],[1,-1,-1]) # (1,24,128)
        bi = tf.slice(b,[i,0,0],[1,-1,-1]) # (1,15,128)
        ci = contact_func(ai,bi) # (1,24,15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `matmul` of the matrix `a` with the transpose of the dimension-1 of `b` should give the desired result:

```
c = tf.matmul(a, tf.transpose(b, [0, 2, 1])) # [1000, 20, 10]

# to get (1000, 20, 10, 1) you do 
tf.expand_dims(c, 3)
```

EDIT:
For the `contact_func` operation, you may need to manually do the broadcasting using `tile` operator. Here is the code for `gaussian distance`:

```
 # use tile to repeat the rows 
 d = tf.reshape(tf.tile(a, [1, 1, b.shape[1]]), (-1,a.shape[1]*b.shape[1],a.shape[2]))
     #[1000, 360, 128], 
 # repeat the columns 
 e = tf.tile(b, [1, a.shape[1], 1])
     #[1000, 360, 128]

 # exp(-d_i_j), where d_i_j is the eucludian distance of i, j
 c = tf.reshape(tf.exp(tf.reduce_sum(d-e, 2)), (-1, a.shape[1], b.shape[1]))  
 #[1000, 24, 15]
```

Comment: thanks a lot and I have modified the question. Could you plz take a look ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with clever application of broadcasting. Try this:

```py
a = tf.ones([1000, 20, 128])
b = tf.ones([1000, 10, 128])

a = tf.expand_dims(a, axis=1)               # [1000, 1, 20, 128]
b = tf.expand_dims(b, axis=2)               # [1000, 10, 1, 128]

products = a * b                            # [1000, 10, 20, 128]
reduced = tf.reduce_sum(products, axis=-1)  # [1000, 10, 20]
```

The `products` contains all pairwise multiplications of all items in `a` and `b`. And the `reduced` aggregates the sum over the last axis.

Comment: thanks a lot and I have modified the question. Could you plz take a look ?

Comment: The method above allows you to compute *any symmetric operation* on `a` and `b`. E.g., for Gaussian distance first compute `x=a-b`, then apply the `exp(-x*x)` and reduce across the desired axis.